# speech to text in hindi for android

Tags: android, google-text-to-speech

I'm using following code and send locale for hindi but still speech to text gives result in English.

I want that result must be in hindi

```
 /**
     * Showing google speech input dialog
     */
    private void promptSpeechInput() {
        Locale locale;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            locale = (Locale.forLanguageTag("hin"));
        } else {
            locale = (new Locale("hin"));
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, locale);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported));
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.otp_send_dynamic_msg),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution , we have to pass a ISO string(in case of hindi its "hi")

```
String languagePref = "hi";
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, languagePref);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, languagePref);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, languagePref);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this :

```
result = (Locale.forLanguageTag("hin"));
```

be

```
locale = (Locale.forLanguageTag("hin"));
```

Comment: I forgot to update here , iam using the same var for both and pass them on intent extra so that is not a problem.

Thanks for your response

Comment: Oh ok. I am not sure it will do anything but you could try to add intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, locale). Also make sure you have the desired TTS voice data installed.